# pytorch.clamp() on a numpy array throws TypeError

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch, typeerror

I have an image that its background is not black while it is supposed to be black. I searched the web for finding a suitable strategy for doing so and I found the `torch.clamp`. My image is like the following:

[image]

When I use the following command:

```
map = torch.clamp(map, Min=0)
```

I receive the following error:

[image]

How I can fix the problem?

Comment: [mre] id required. show the code that produces `map` and show us what you need `map` for after this operation.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass to the function a Tensor array, not a numpy array, it gives something like this at the end:

```
map_ = torch.clamp(torch.from_numpy(map_), min=0).numpy()
```

Comment: in case the result needs to be a numpy array again, just use `np.clip()`

Answer (score 2):

If only the `min` argument is used, [`numpy.maximum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html) can do the same thing:

```
>>> np.maximum(np.arange(-10, 10), 0)
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```